# Cannot Resolve R after update

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I just updated Android studio and every java file now has a cannot resolve R error.

I have tried rebuilding and cleaning the project nothing has fixed it.

I am not sure what code to show you all since I didn't change any since the update...

Comment: Try reimporting the project. It will regenerate the R file.

Comment: check you dont have a error in xml file

Comment: try to restart,refresh,clean and build alternately. Sometimes it may take time but it will eventually generate R.java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** of all you have to restart `Android Studio`. Believe me a lot of `Eclipse` and `Android Studio` un-logical issues can be solved by restarting the IDE.

**Second**, the IDE will not be able to successfully build the project and correctly import `R` if there is any problem in your `.XML` files. So, if you cannot determine the problem from the error window in the IDE. Then you have to quickly go through your `.XML` files.

**Third**, make sure you are not coping into your application `resources` a file with un-acceptable naming. Such as:

-Image name starting with number.

-Image name contains "-".

-Image name with spaces...etc.

Answer (score 0):

File -> invalidate cache and restart